# Solve the complex equation $0=z^3+3z^2+4z-8$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I solve $$0=z^3+3z^2+4z-8$$
I don't have any formula or initial idea to solve it. Thanks

Comment: To find rational solutions: try numerator is a factor of $8$ (the constant term) and denominator is a factor of $1$ (the coefficient of the leading term $z^3$).  This gives you eight things to try:  $1,2,4,8,-1,-2,-4,-8$.  (All rational solutions must be in this list.) This is how you could start, and reach the hint of HAMIDINE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$z^3+3z^2+4z−8 = (z-1)(z^2+4z+8)$

So, the three roots are 1, -2+2i, -2-2i.

Answer (score 4):

$1$ is solution. Can you find the two others?

Comment: +1 for starting then letting the OP finish.